# Need proofing on this 12v battery protection circuit

Tags: arduino, current, schematics, ohms-law, over-discharge

I am making a battery protection board for my 12v battery. The amperage pulled from the battery could go up to as much as 20A. I want the Arduino (connected to the protection board) to activate the relay, and open the circuit in the case of overcurrent or over-discharge (using spectroscopy to detect the battery SoC).

The problem is that I need proofing on this. I am kind of a newbie to this and lacking confidence in whether this circuit will actually work.

NOTES: The flat ground symbol is for the battery's ground. The triangular ground symbol is for the Arduino's ground

[image]

1. Is there anything missing/ unnecessary/ wired incorrectly that could cause damage to any part of this circuit or the Arduino?
2. are the values for the resistors (R1,R2,R21) correct? I used ohms law, but something tells me on R1 and R2 that .25Ω is not sufficient to reduce the 12v 20A down to 5v. Same concerns for R21.

   1. … And do I need to add a resistor to from the Arduino digital pin, to the transistor?
3. Will this circuit enable the Arduino to use ohms law to get the amperage from the battery? if not what changes must I do to the circuit, or is it even possible?
4. Lastly, does this circuit provide all the data necessary to the Arduino for the Impedance Spectroscopy State of charge (SoC) method?

Comment: The negative side of the load is only connected to the Arduino analog input A1 trough R1 so the load cannot be powered. A0 is connected straight to ground and will always read 0. The transistor needs a base resistor and should be switching the low side of the relay. 0.165 ohm current limiting resistor for a LED? ...

Comment: What are A0 and A1 doing on the Arduino? What is the purpose of R1 and R2? Why is R21 0.165 ohms? Where is the Arduino getting its power from?

Comment: Try [this](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/ohms-law/latest/ohms-law_en.html) to get an intuitive sense of Ohm's Law.

Comment: the transistor emitter should be connected to ground ... the relay solenoid pin 1 should be connected to battery positive

Comment: This is *dangerously* confused in terms of basic circuit concepts to be an attempt to design what appears to be supposed to be a safety system.  Please do not pursue this as a DIY project, rather buy something suitable.

Comment: OK. where would I buy something like that? @ChrisStratton

Comment: Depends on the application; it might be as simple as an automotive fuse or circuit breaker.  But there's not enough detail here.

Comment: Its for a NiCd battery. The only protection boards (over discharge, overcharge) they sell are for Li-ion. Would they be compatible with NiCd? @ChrisStratton

Comment: No, they should only be used for the intended battery type.  For a NiCd *discharge* only case you would typically use an automotive fuse.

Comment: OK. thanks.   ---

Answer (score 0):

This circuit will not work.  There are many problems and it's hard to understand exactly what you mean.

1. all load current (20a) will return through a1 - Arduino microcontrol pins can't support that current and will break.
2. there is no resistor on gate of transistor - this will break digital pin.
3. when/if the relay activates the led will draw massive current and break.

There are more - but I suggest some more reading or following a reference diagram would help.  I know electronics is difficult and don't mean to be discouraging!

Comment: "General indefinite power +" is always connected to the LED. It doesn't need the relay to switch to break.

Comment: Yes but it's indefinite ;) the relay will definitely connect it.

Comment: What should the transistor's resistor be rated at? previously I had a transistor rated for 4.7kΩ. But according to ohms law, it would only amplify the 5v from the Arduino to 23,500v @CalumNicoll

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something with ohms law, will someone please give me a little help on this? Obviously .165 ohms will do almost nothing to protect the LED. The voltage going thru the LED would only be 3.3v and the current would be 121A (V = 20A * 0.165Ω) (A = 12v / 0.165Ω) @CalumNicoll